# Embedded H2 Database Connection Error - wrong username and password

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, h2

I'm struggling with Hibernate, JavaEE Persistence and an embedded H2-Database.

I've got the following section in my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="iot_pu">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:/tmp/databases/iot;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MVCC=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory

        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at iot.utils.AbstractTestSuite.setUpClass(AbstractTestSuite.java:22)
        at iot.utils.AbstractTestSuite.getEmf(AbstractTestSuite.java:37)
        at iot.utils.AbstractTest.init
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Falscher Benutzer Name oder Passwort
Wrong user name or password [28000-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:333)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:136)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect
```

If I test the connection with IntelliJ it says that the connection works without problems - no username or password.
[image]
[image]

The line that causes the problem (AbstractTestSuite.java:22) says

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("iot_pu");
```

Can it be the case, that I've forgot something to import via Maven?

```
.........
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
.........
```

Comment: I think you have missed username and password in connection url

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `hibernate.connection.username` and `hibernate.connection.password` properties in your `persistence.xml`, or you can insert them directly in your connection URL (example: `"jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@127.0.0.1:1521:SMIDVINT"`).

Comment: I've already added them, but there is still the same error. I also tried the default username "sa"...but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Test your connection with this to make sure your setting is correct :

```
    /**
     * Connect to H2db.
     * calling example:  connect("jdbc:h2:/Resources/databases/dbName", "JohnD", "secret")
     */
    public static Connection connect (String dbPath, String userName, String password)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, JdbcSQLException  {

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        String dbURL= dbPath + ";IGNORECASE=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;IFEXISTS=TRUE";

        return DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,userName,password);
    }
```